# MapR client not executing hadoop - Windows

Tags: hadoop, elastic-map-reduce, mapr

I have an Amazon Windows VM where i did install `MapR-Client 2.1.2`, and another MapR cluster waiting for the jobs to be executed.
I set up `MAPR_HOME` in `C:\opt\mapr`, and when I execute

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

from `C:\opt\mapr\hadoop\hadoop-0.20.2\bin` I get:

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

I also configured the `MapR-Client` with 
`server\configure.bat -c -C <ip_addr>:7222`
and in `config\mapr-clusters.conf` I can see:

```
my.cluster.com <ip_addr>:7222
```

Also I made sure I'm able to ping and ssh from the Windows `MapR Client` to the cluster master ... 
Could someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Please use

hadoop.bat fs -ls /

and let me know if it's working.